# Clarification on upgrading the OS and using OWC SSD?

Tags: macos, ssd

I have a Early 2015 version Macbook Pro which has 126 GB HD / 10.11.1 El Captain OS on it. I wanted to upgrade the SSD. I decided to go with OWC. Transcend Jetdrive 820 for my Macbook model is on bit higher price.

However, OWC doesn't support El Captain. Whether it is possible to upgrade the OS to High Sierra on the current SSD and then replace the SSD with OWC SSD? Whether that will work?

Comment: Can I assume you are also getting Envoy Pro Enclosure? If not, then how are you going to transfer your data to the new SSD?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the Enclosure whatever comes with OWC. I agree with you, Existing SSD which came in the Macbook will be moved to the Enclosure.  My primary concern is about replacing the SSD to my Macbook.

Answer (score 2):

Where does it say OWC doesn't support El Captain? I can not image why the version of macOS would matter. I assume you would put the new drive in the computer and then install the current macOS. Afterwards you would run the Migration Assistant to copy your files to the new SSD.

In other words, I do not see the need to change or update your existing drive before swapping with the new SSD.

Comment: It says on the product specification. I called OWC customer support, they mentioned the same .. OS has to be High Sierra

Comment: https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/S3DAPB4MB05K/    Under system compatibility- says designed for High Sierra. So the MacBook has to upgraded with High Sierra before replacing the SSD